# Has more than one entry point defined error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyWindow : Window
    {
        public MyWindow()
        {
            Width = 300; Height = 200; Title = "My Program Window";
            Content = "This application handles the Startup event.";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The application is starting", "Starting Message");
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            MyWindow win = new MyWindow();

            Application app = new Application();
            app.Startup += App_Startup;

            app.Run(win);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Error    1    Program
> 'c:...\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\obj\Debug\WpfApplication2.exe'
> has more than one entry point defined:
> 'WpfApplication2.Program.Main()'.  Compile with /main to specify the
> type that contains the entry point.

There isn't any "Program" file in my code as far as I see. How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look in your App.xaml. Is there in the Application-Tag the StartupUri set?

Comment: I have this in App.xaml :   StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
Should I delete that line?

Comment: I suggest you could delete `static void Main()` as `App.xaml` is more appropriate for determining WPF startup

Comment: @pushpraj then how could I implement Main's functionality? Thanks.

Comment: @jason there's probably an event you can subscribe to or a method you can `override`, that will be invoked during initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two primary options to implement on start activities:

#### Event handlers

File *App.xaml*

```xml
<Application x:Class="CSharpWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Define `Startup="Application_Startup"` and handle in file *App.xaml.cs*:

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // On start stuff here
    }
```

#### Override method

File *App.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // On start stuff here
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Or here, where you find it more appropriate
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be the intended way to do this, but it's still possible to specify a custom Main method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156550/replacing-the-wpf-entry-point

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this error, *don't* change the name of the .cs file when creating new code.

If you want a new name for your .cs file then you have to delete everything in the folder where your project is i.e., the fragments of files (bin, obj folders, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `<StartupObject>` element in your project's *.csproj* file, eg.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <StartupObject>WpfApplication2.Program</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```