# Get exit from WPF application in command shell

Tags: c#, wpf, exit-code, entry-point

I have a WPF application that  takes command line arguments and in some cases returns an exit value without starting the App. I have replaced the entry point as in this question [Replacing the WPF entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156550/replacing-the-wpf-entry-point). 
When I run in Visual Studio without an argument it launches my App as expected. When I supply an argument it all looks good I get a line telling me "The program XXX has exited with code 66"

When I then run from the CMD command line without an argument it launches the app as expected. When I supply an argument and look at %ERRORLEVEL% I get an exit code of 0 not 66. What gives here ?

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{

  public class EntryPoint
  {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            if (args.Count > 0)
            {
                Environment.Exit(66);
            }
            App.Main();
    }
  }

  public partial class App : Application
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a quick c# console app to call the app using Process.Start and report the exit code and it correctly reported an exit code of 66 when I run my app with an argument. So purely something wrong on command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is windowed, and runs in the background as far as the command window is concerned, so `%errorlevel%` only shows that the application was launched. When your application later exits, the exit code is lost.

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11476681, if you launch your application with `START /WAIT`, then the command window will wait for your application to exit and store the exit code in `%errorlevel%`.